# Google identity toolkit for python incomplete response

Tags: python, heroku, flask, google-identity-toolkit

I have a python/flask app set up with google identity toolkit. When I run it on localhost, when I perform `gitkit_instance.VerifyGitkitToken` I get back all of the user's details, including user id, name, email, and photo url. However when I deploy the app to heroku, the login still appears to work, and I get back the user id and email address, but the other fields (name, photo url) are blank. This is for the same user in both cases. Is this a heroku deployment issue or is something else going on?

Comment: Which identity provider did you test with, Google, Facebook, or others? Is your heroku app publicly accessible?

Comment: Identity provider is google, and yes the heroku app is publicly accessible

Comment: Do you mind to share your heroku app URL? Or if you prefer to be contacted by the Google Identity Toolkit team in private, you can re-post this question to the official forum https://groups.google.com/forum/?place=forum/google-identity-toolkit